# How to receive 2-byte decimal number from Bluetooth to arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I can send 1byte decimal number (0-256) easily over arduino, but I couldn't make it for 2 byte number.

the code below here I used for sending data between 0-256, this is works great.

```html
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <Servo.h> 
Servo myservo;

int bluetoothTx = 10;
int bluetoothRx = 11;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(9);
  //Setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if(bluetooth.available()> 0 )
  {
    int servopos = bluetooth.read();
    Serial.println(servopos); 
    myservo.write(servopos);
  }


}
```

I tried to program for 2 byte number , but I couldn't make it successfully , MSB and LSB data are not shifting properly . any help regarding this code will be much help for me go ahead .

```html
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <Servo.h> 
Servo myservo;

int bluetoothTx = 7;
int bluetoothRx = 8;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(9);
  //Setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if(bluetooth.available()>= 2 )
  {
    int servopos = bluetooth.read() << 8;
    servopos |= bluetooth.read();
    Serial.println(servopos); 
    myservo.write(servopos);
  }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "MSB and LSB data are not shifting properly"? If you can't get the MSB then probably it's because the "read" function returns a byte, so try casting it before shifting: `int servopos = ((int)bluetooth.read()) << 8;`. If only the first bit of the MSB is changed then the problem is a signed/unsigned problem, so try defining `servopos` as an `unsigned int` (and cast to an `unsigned int` too). If, on the other side, you get two swapped bytes, read something about endianness (e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)), then just swap them.